# Cannot attach UI Text object to serialized field on Prefab in Unity 5.0.2f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Using Unity 5.0.2f1 for Mac.

Created a UI Text object (called LifeCountUI) in the scene. Then, on my Player's script (attached to my Player GameObject), I have the following field serialized:

```
[SerializeField]
public Text LifeCountText;
```

This Player GameObject is also a prefab.

My intention was to drag the LifeCountUI in the inspector to the serialized field on the Player GameObject. However, Unity does not allow me to do this when I select the Player prefab.

It only works, if I drag an instance of the Player prefab on to the scene, and then drag the LifeCountUI to the field (but obviously, that is not the prefab).

Am I doing something wrong here? I essentially want to have the ability to control the text field from the prefab instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at what gurus say about it in famouse [50 Tips for Working with Unity (Best Practices)](http://devmag.org.za/2012/07/12/50-tips-for-working-with-unity-best-practices/) article:

> 18. Link prefabs to prefabs; do not link instances to instances. Links to prefabs are maintained when dropping a prefab into a scene; links to instances are not. Linking to prefabs whenever possible reduces scene setup, and reduce the need to change scenes.

This is one of reason you are unable to maintain a reference.

Comment: OK fair point. I will grab it through the Player instance instead. Thanks.